# is it possible to capture an app http requests from appium android/ios simulators?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, appium-android, appium-ios

I am working with ruby-cucumber And I need to capture a request and modify response made from an app running on (appium) android and ios simulators , is there a way to do this?
thanks a lot